# "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." error

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, advanced-installer

I am using Advanced Installer Enterprise and my requirement is to build an installer that downloads/installs an .exe setup file from remote location.

I followed these steps:

1. Create a project using Enterprise template.
2. Create a Featured-Based package using New URL Prerequisite (with correct Display Name, URL, and Silent install parameter /SILENT).

But whenever I run my new installer, I get the follow error (see image below) when it finish downloading my .exe setup file from remote location.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Is this an Advanced Installer error or is this an error from my OS?

I am using Windows 7 with Advanced Installer 11.8.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error from Advanced Installer, it is a generic error from the OS. Not sure why you are receiving it, if you search Google you'll find all kind of cases.

To help you more you can post a [verbose log](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html) (link it from pastebin) or send it by email at support at advancedinstaller dot com if it contains confidential info.

If you'll send it by email you might as well include the project file from Advanced Installer, to compare it against the log.